# Can't get active route params

Tags: angular, typescript

I can not get active route parameters. When I console log I  just get this [image]. This demo code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mkp9h)

**Code**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((v) => {
      // this.params = v;
      console.log(v);
    })
    
  }

}
```

**routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

Comment: What's the route definition, what params were you expecting? Put a [mre] *in the question*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `ActivatedRoute's "params"` is only applicable when your route has an actual parameters being declared on your paths:

```
// So the parameter here is the ID
{ path: 'login/:id', component: HelloComponent },
```

you can declare any parameters in your route and any names you prefer

```
{ path: 'login/:userId', component: HelloComponent },

or 

{ path: 'login/:userId/:role', component: HelloComponent },
```

---

If you only want to get the current path without any extra parameters, you can implement it this way instead:

```
@Component({...})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router) {}    // Use Router instead of ActivatedRoute

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.router.url);           // Get current route
                                              // if the url is "http://example.com/login" it will console /login
    }
    
}
```

Comment: why it should add `ID`?

Comment: You can add anything, that's just an example :) have updated the sample above for more examples

Comment: You can access them from the route snapshot normally without registrating them

Comment: @LotteLemmens how to access them without registrating them? Could you give example?

Comment: @KShewengger if I using `routing.module` like in my question what should I do?

Comment: this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['insert specified item here'];

Comment: @Pravu Have forked your stackblitz demo, you can try accessing it with /login/1 or any params you want to fill in then the activated params will log { id: 1 }, Note that your path in your module should be"login/:id" not "login:id" https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjh9ud?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: when I add `login/:id` I need to add like this `login/test` then got detect `{id: "test"}`.. I just want it detect `login` without extra id

Comment: Have updated the Stackblitz Demo, you can just fill in the path with just `":id"` or `":path"`, you can name the parameter any name you prefer :)  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjh9ud?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @Pravu have updated my answer above, if you want to get the current route without any extra parameters :)

Comment: @KShewengger yup this is what I want... thank you so much sis..One more question how to remove `/`..Because when I console log I got this `/login`

Comment: @Pravu no problem, that would be easy with regex or split, have updated the Stackblitz Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjh9ud?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/hello.component.ts